# What ntpq command or configuration setting would show output from a statum 1 server?

Tags: ntp

How can I tell ntpq to output servers other than stratum 2?

Currently
`ntpq -p` prints [this](http://pastebin.com/J7yu2nTR). But what I need is at least one stratum 1 server in the output.

I've read [here](http://doc.ntp.org/4.1.0/ntpq.htm) and [here](http://perdues.com/doc/ntp.html). I've also tried adding a stratum 1 [server](http://support.ntp.org/bin/view/Servers/PublicTimeServer001110) to the /etc/ntp.conf file, but that did not change the output. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you **need** to sync to a stratum 1 server? NTP is designed to stay within a few milliseconds of "true" time, even after that time filters through numerous strata. The S1 servers tend to be heavily loaded, so it's often more polite to query S2 or S3 servers (e.g. the NTP pool) if you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're actually sync'ing to a stratum one server, it'll happily print it out:

```
anthony@Watt:~$ ntpq -p
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
-xen1.rack911.co 66.228.59.187    3 u  737 1024  377   81.085   -2.838   1.015
+clock.xmission. .GPS.            1 u  512 1024  377   76.454   -6.912  10.883
+time-c.nist.gov .ACTS.           1 u  169 1024  377    9.470    1.294  29.911
*clock1.alb1.ino .CDMA.           1 u  980 1024  377   29.739   -4.838  11.728
```

Make sure to restart ntp after modifying its configuration file. I don't even see `level1e.cs.unc.edu` in your output at all. (BTW: The server list above is from using the NTP Pool, it's not hand-configured.)

Comment: Thank you so much, I'd just forgotten to restart the service, so `/etc/init.d/ntp restart` worked.